# oracle temporary tablespace not taking all the place he has

Tags: oracle, temporary-files, temporary, tablespace

I got a problem with my temporary tablespace. I'm on Oracle.
I need a temporary tablespace of about 8G for an import. Problem is I don't have that much place in just one place of my server.
So I did multiple tempfiles :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP_X0DDBA TEMPFILE
'/var/X0DNAT_temp01.dbf' SIZE 1536M,
'/var/log/audit/X0DNAT_temp02.dbf' SIZE 1740M,
'/logiciels/X0DNAT_temp03.dbf' SIZE 2662M,
'/appli/projects/X0DNAT_temp04.dbf' SIZE 1126M,
'/logiciels/oracle/diag/X0DNAT_temp05.dbf' SIZE 1228M,
'/home/oracle/X0DNAT_temp06.dbf' SIZE 1843M;
```

Total, I could have a temporary tablespace of 9.8G.

But I think that Oracle is fulling the different files fairly. And when 1 of the files is full it stops the execution and says that files are full :

When I check the size of temp files, I got this :

```
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME, sum(BYTES)/1024/1024 FROM DBA_TEMP_FILES group by TABLESPACE_NAME;

TABLESPACE_NAME                                   SUM(BYTES)/1024/1024
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------
TEMP_X0DDBA                                                      10135
```

But when I check the size of the tablespace :

```
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME, SUM(BYTES_USED)/1024/1024 from V$TEMP_SPACE_HEADER group by TABLESPACE_NAME;

TABLESPACE_NAME                              SUM(BYTES_USED)/1024/1024
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------
TEMP_X0DDBA                                                       6707
```

So clearly the tablespace isn't taking all the space he has in files.

Do you know how to make it take all the place he has, and not fairly between files ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you running an oracle database on a server which doesn't have room for an 8Gb temporary tablespace?

Comment: @APC It's not my server (client's). And it's almost full.